# How to add a permanent filter function to a List view in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I a react-admin list view I want to display only records with a status value >2. `status` is a custom field.

The permanent filter section of the react-admin documentation (see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html) only refers to static filters which checks for a specific field value like

```
export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} filter={{ is_published: true }}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

but I'd like to pass a filter function like:

```
export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} filter={()=>(status.id > 2)}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

Unfortunately this does not work. `status` is unknown and even if I return a static true or false it has no effect on filtering.

Is there another way or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-admin doesn't have any knowledge of how your API does "greater than" or "less than" queries (because there is no standard for that). The react-admin permanent filters are passed to your dataProvider, which passes them to your API.

So I advise you to use a special filter key in you list, as follows:

```
export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} filter={{ status_id_gt: 2 }}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

Then, in your dataProvider, detect the usage of that filter, and transform it into whatever your API expects for a "greater than" filter.

Comment: The api does not support filtering anyway, it should be done client-side, that means react-admin needs to fetch all records once and then apply paging or filtering on that dynamically. Is that supported?

Comment: thats actually another question: how to make react-admin paging and filtering if the given api only supports 'get all' (and ignoring all paging/filtering parameters)  and 'get one'

Comment: You can do the filtering and sorting client-side, in your dataProvider. the important thing is that the dataProvider returns the filtered and sorted data.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that this would be the answer. I used filter={{ filter_type: 'id_gt_2' }} at the end and implemented it in the data provider. I was hoping that react_admin supports client side filtering ootb somehow.